# Remove cookie from GeckoFx C#

Tags: c#, cookies, interface, geckofx

I want to remove cookie of a site in `Geckofx FireFox Browser`.
I find this

```
Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsICookieManager>((object)Xpcom.GetService<nsICookieManager>("@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1")).Remove(...);
```

and

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface nsICookieManager
{
    void RemoveAll();
    nsISimpleEnumerator GetEnumeratorAttribute();
    void Remove(nsAUTF8StringBase aHost, nsACStringBase aName,    nsAUTF8StringBase aPath, bool aBlocked);
}
```

I am confused with the parameter of it, for example:
`nsAUTF8StringBase`

```
 public class nsAUTF8StringBase : IString
{
    protected nsAUTF8StringBase();

    protected static int NS_CStringContainerFinish(nsAUTF8StringBase container);
    protected static int NS_CStringContainerInit(nsAUTF8StringBase container);
    protected static int NS_CStringGetData(nsAUTF8StringBase str, out IntPtr data, IntPtr nullTerm);
    protected static bool NS_CStringGetIsVoid(nsAUTF8StringBase str);
    protected static int NS_CStringSetData(nsAUTF8StringBase str, byte[] data, int length);
    protected static void NS_CStringSetIsVoid(nsAUTF8StringBase str, bool isVoid);
    public virtual void SetData(string value);
    public override string ToString();
}
```

how i should create "aHost"? and how i can remove a site cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three ways which you could try

1  - If you know the cookie name, host and path, you can do the following (instantiate the string parameters):

```
 nsICookieManager cookieMan = Xpcom.GetService<nsICookieManager>("@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1");
 cookieMan = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsICookieManager>(cookieMan);
 cookieMan.Remove(new nsAUTF8String("SomeHost"),new nsACString("SomeName"), new nsAUTF8String("SomePath"),false);
```

2 - use the `Gecko.CookieManager` static class which can remove the cookies based on plain string parameters (see details below)

3 - If you don't know all the info about the cookie you want to delete (you know only the value or name or something), then you can use the `Gecko.CookieManager` to enumerate the cookies and delete it.

```
        var cookies = CookieManager.GetEnumerator();

        while (cookies.MoveNext())
        {
            if (cookies.Current.Name == "CookieIHate")
            {
                CookieManager.Remove(cookies.Current.Host, cookies.Current.Name, cookies.Current.Path, false);
            }
        }
```